# CSS flip Issue with Firefox mouse-hover

Tags: html, css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a CSS flip effect on my site. I got this “css-flip” from [this website](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip).

It’s working perfectly in all browsers, only issue is, when checking in Firefox, after flipping there is flashing black color between paragraphs like this:

[image: flip-image].

It is showing that color just for a second. How to avoid this?

[This is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/0xpvykrp/):

```css
/* entire container, keeps perspective */

.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
/*  UPDATED! flip the pane when hovered */

.flip-container:hover .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-container:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
}
/* flip speed goes here */

.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
/*  UPDATED! front pane, placed above back */

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
/* back, initially hidden pane */

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  background-color: #5fae25 !important;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="m-b20 bg-white shadow front">

      <div class=services-wrap>
        <a href=callcenter-services.htm style=text-decoration:none>
          <div class="text-center">
            <span class="icon-circle"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i></span>
            <h5 class="text-center services-head m-t20">CALL CENTER SERVICE</h5>
            <p class="gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed nec.</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class=clearfix></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.
        <br />This is nice for exposing more information about an image.
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class=clearfix></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't recreate this issue with the provided code in Firefox 38.0.5

Comment: I couldn't find out a solution, guessing this is a bug of FF, so reported there and waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your *fiddle* on all browsers and its working fine here on my side, even tested on both available versions of Firfox (Native as well as Developer Edition).
Just make sure you follow Cross-Browser Compatible CSS formatting (like -webkit-, -o- etc) for the every effects you're using.

Comment: Jsfiddle also showing here.. for realtime testing, plz create an HTML test page,